# Unable to send cookie with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

Tried adding `{withCredentials: true}` but still unable to send cookie to backend

```js
return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/posts/category/${id}`, {
  withCredentials: true
})
```

[image]

Cookie

[image]

Comment: Is the cookie relevant to the `API_URL` domain?

Comment: @Phil front end is on port 4200 and backend on port 3333 both running on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're sending the `{ withCredentials: true }` object as the 2nd parameter to `axios.post()`. The [signature](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) for that function is

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

Typically with a POST request you'll want to send *some* data but if you really want to skip it, pass `undefined` as the 2nd parameter

```js
return axios.post(`/posts/category/${id}`, undefined, {
  baseURL: API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

---

I highly recommend taking advantage of Axios' ability to create customised instances with convenient defaults

```js
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});

// ...

return apiClient.post(`/posts/category/${id}`); // much easier
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this answer on the Internet, hope it will help you.
Since 2020, Chrome add more annoying restricts to cross domain cookies settings, you must set cookies with SameSite to none, otherwise Chrome will refuse to send cookies. More, if you set SameSite, you must set secure.

```
proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; SameSite=none";
```